# connect to access 2000 database using Excel 2016?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access-2000

We have an Access 2000 database that cannot be upgraded or changed.
For Office, the only version in our organization is Office 2016.
I need to write a vba script from Excel that reads data from that Access 2000.
I've tried

```
ConnectionStr = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB4.0;Data Source=theaccess2000.mdb"
connection.Open
```

and received the error

> "Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed."

I think the machine is 64bit.
Could someone please help as to what need to be installed/configured on the machine so that excel16 can connect to that old access2000?  Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Try with the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` provider. For further informations: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff965871(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Thanks Florent, but it doesn't like the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 .  it says "Cannot open a database created with a previous version of your application"

Comment: Looks like there's no 64 bits version of the `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB4.0` provider. So your best chance is probably to export the file as CSV on a 32bits Office or with an external tool like https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Convert-Access-to-CSV-File-0345a8a3#content

Answer (score 0):

Check the access connection strings here:
https://www.connectionstrings.com

About 20 are used for [Access 2000](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2000/):

*Standard security (mdb file):*

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.mdb;
Persist Security Info=False;
```

*With database password (mdb file):*

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.mdb;
Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword;
```

*DataDirectory functionality (mdb file):*

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\myAccessFile.mdb;
Persist Security Info=False;
```

*Network Location (mdb file):*

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
Data Source=\\serverName\shareName\folder\myAccessFile.mdb;
```

Comment: Thanks Vityata, but when I used Microsfot.ACE.OLEDB.12.0, it says "Cannot open a database created with a previous version of your application"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you miss a dot and probably the full path as well:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=d:\somefolder\theaccess2000.mdb"
```